# How to solve this error Plug-in "org.eclipse.egit.ui" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.staging.StagingView".?

Tags: java, git, spring-boot

[unable to see git stagging area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCMbk.png)

Unable to connect to git staging are only not visible and getting this error `org.eclipse.egit.ui` was unable to instantiate class

```
org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.staging.StagingView. Its telling internal error occured in  Git Repository Change Scanner
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace to the question ... and [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).  The complete stacktrace may have clues that help to explain *why* Eclipse was unable to instantiate the class.